# Why does my variant return a value not equal to what it was assigned?

Tags: c++, variant

I am trying to create a simple variant as a learning exercise.

I want to do this without dynamically allocating memory, as is specified by the c++ specification for `std::variant`.

To simplify things, my variant can only take two values.

Here is my implementation:

```
//variant style class for two types
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class Either {
    using Bigest = std::conditional<sizeof(T1) >= sizeof(T2), T1, T2>;
    using ByteArray = std::array<std::byte, sizeof(Bigest)>;

    ByteArray val;
    std::optional<std::type_index> containedType;

public:

    Either() : containedType(std::nullopt) {} 

    template<typename T>
    Either(const T& actualVal) : containedType(typeid(T)) {         //ToDo check T is one of correct types
        ByteArray* ptr = (ByteArray*)&actualVal;
        val = *ptr;
    }

    class BadVariantAccess {};

    template<typename T>
    inline T& getAs() const {
        if(containedType == typeid(T)) {
            T* ptr = (T*)val.data();
            return *ptr;
        }
        else throw BadVariantAccess();
    }
};
```

However, when I test this I get an incorrect number after trying to get the value:

```
int main() {

    Either<int,float> e = 5;

    std::cout << e.getAs<int>() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Returns a random number (e.g 272469509).

What is the problem with my implementation, and how can I fix it?

Comment: `&actualVal` in your constructor is highly suspect. How do you think you managed to get the address of the literal 5?

Comment: @Mat good point. I don't think this is the only problem though. I tried first creating `int a = 5`, and then assigning e to a, but I still get a random number.

Comment: You probably meant to use `std::conditional_t` for `Biggest`, rather than just `std::conditional`.  As is, `ByteArray` is likely an alias for `std::array<std::byte, 1>`.

Comment: `T* ptr = (T*)val.data();` Ouch

Comment: `val = *ptr;` is a strict aliasing violation.  Also this will read out of bounds of the source, if the source type is not the biggest

Comment: I usually stay away from very low level memory stuff so this is new to me. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program exhibits Undefined Behavior for various reasons, so it's a bit meaningless to attempt to explain why you observe the given behaviour. But here are some serious issues with your code:

1. It's not safe to alias any memory as `std::array<std::byte, N>`. This is a violation of the Strict Aliasing Rule, the only exceptions to which are pointers to `char` and `std::byte`. When doing `ByteArray* ptr = (ByteArray*)&actualVal; val = *ptr;`, you are invoking `std::array's` copy constructor and passing an instance that does not exist. At this point, literally anything could happen. You should instead be either copying bytes one-by-one (for trivial types), or using placement `new` to copy-construct an object in your byte-based storage.
2. Your storage is not aligned, and this can cause crashes or serious performance penalties at runtime, depending on your target platform. I'm not immediately sure whether this can cause Undefined Behaviour but you should certainly address this if you want to continue with such low-level memory management.
3. Your copy constructor does not check the actual size in memory of the type being assigned. If, on some platform, you have `sizeof(int) > sizeof(float)`, then when you copy-construct an `Either<int, float>` from a `float`, you will read bytes past the end of the float and easily cause Undefined Behavior. You must take the size of the type being assigned into account
4. If you plan to store anything but trivial types (i.e. `std::string` or `std::vector`, not just primitives), you'll need to make calls to the appropriate copy/move constructor/assignment operators. For constructors (default, move, copy), you'll need to use placement `new` to construct live objects in the pre-allocated storage. Furthermore, you'll need to use type-erasure to store some function that will destroy the contained object as the correct type. A lambda inside a `std::function<void(std::byte*)>` could be very useful here, which simply calls the destructor: `[](std::byte* data){ (*reinterpret_cast<T*>(data)).~T(); }` This would have to be assigned anytime you store a new type. Note that this sort of situation is just about the only time you would ever manually want to call a destructor.

I strongly urge you to do some careful reading about how to do such low-level memory management correctly. It's really easy to do incorrectly and not have any idea until you get plagued with bizarre bugs much later.

---

As was kindly pointed out by @MilesBudnek, `using Biggest = std::conditional<sizeof(T1) >= sizeof(T2), T1, T2>` will give the type *trait*, and so an instance of `Biggest` will actually be an instance of a specialization of the struct `std::conditional` and *not* `T1` or `T2`. You probably meant `std::conditional_t<...>` or `std::conditional<...>::type;` This likely has the effect that your `Either` class will only ever allocate a single byte, which is obviously incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. As I mentioned, this is purely a learning exercise and I would never do this in anything but a toy program.

I tried changing the ctor to  `for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(T); i++) { val[i] = }` but am unsure what to asign to.

I also changed val to an  `alignas(sizeof(Bigest)) ByteArray val;`. 

You are correct about the conditional.

What should I assign the bytes of val to?

Thanks.

Comment: @Blue7 you can alias `actualVal` as a sequence of bytes like this: `const auto src = reinterpret_cast<const std::byte*>(&actualVal);` and read that like a normal array.

Comment: Better would be to do something like `new (val.data()) T{actualVal}`.  That would support non-trivial types.  You would need to add a destructor that calls the contained type's destructor though.

Comment: @MilesBudnek I'm trying to do this without dynamic memory allocation. As 'std::variant' does not. I cannot for the life of me understand GCCs implementation so I thought I might understand more if I just try to make one.

Comment: @Blue7 standard libraries implementations are not written for legibility, let me tell you...

Comment: @Blue7 Placement-new does not do any dynamic allocation.  It just constructs an object in already-allocated storage.  In this case, it would be copy-constructing a new `T` object into the memory pointed to by `val.data()`.

Comment: If you wouldn't do it in a real program, don't do it in a toy program either. Otherwise what, really, are you playing with, and why? UB isn't just a theoretical concern, something we can live with as long as we don't want production quality. It causes _real, practical, symptoms_. There is _never_ an excuse for it, not in any category of program. At all. Period.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings when I say a Toy program, I mean a program that is written just to see what happens, out of curiosity, in order to understand the intricacies of the language. I asked this question to find where the UB was and to replace it with something that will work. I have now done it!

Answer (score 1):

```
    ByteArray* ptr = (ByteArray*)&actualVal;
```

This is nonsensical. You are saying that `ptr` points to a `std::array`, but it doesn't. Of course you'll get garbage if you dereference it.

Comment: You say "of course" even though it's a very widely held [mis]conception that aliasing like this should work, because "it's just bytes". Saw it at work just the other week and had to argue for literally hours about it. Apparently, to many programmers (particularly those not familiar with abstractions), this is not obvious. Accordingly, this answer might be better if it went into more detail than just insulting the code quality ;)